# Variable Availability in Erlang

Tags: function, variables, erlang, global

I am wondering if it is possible to have a function get a variable if it is not passed explicitly.

The issue is mainly about cleaning up my code, as I have many functions that need to pass every variable that will ever be used to the next function.

In SML for example, one could easily accomplish this with something like:

```
fun myFun varx vary varz
   let
     fun otherFun () = varx
     fun otherFun2 () = vary
   in
     otherFun() + otherFun()
end
```

Is there a way to allow other functions to see variables that are not explicitly passed to it? Or is this just not the way one would program in erlang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erlang variable scope works much in the same way:

E.g:

```
add_two(X) ->
 F = fun(Y) ->
         X + Y
     end,
  F(2).
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But it only works when defining a closure/fun, you cannot create functions which are local to another function.